# NumPy exception when using MLlib even though Numpy is installed

Tags: python, numpy, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib

Here's the code I'm trying to execute:

```
from pyspark.mllib.recommendation import ALS
iterations=5
lambdaALS=0.1
seed=5L
rank=8
model=ALS.train(trainingRDD,rank,iterations, lambda_=lambdaALS, seed=seed)
```

When I run the `model=ALS.train(trainingRDD,rank,iterations, lambda_=lambdaALS, seed=seed)` command that depends on numpy, the Py4Java library that Spark uses throws the following message:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o587.trainALSModel.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 67.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 67.0 (TID 195, 192.168.161.55): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/platform/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 98, in main
    command = pickleSer._read_with_length(infile)
  File "/home/platform/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 164, in _read_with_length
    return self.loads(obj)
  File "/home/platform/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 421, in loads
    return pickle.loads(obj)
  File "/home/platform/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/mllib/__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
Exception: MLlib requires NumPy 1.4+
```

NumPy 1.10 is installed on the machine stated in the error message.
Moreover I get version 1.9.2 when executing the following command directly in my Jupyter notebook: 
`import numpy`
`numpy.version.version`

I am obviously running a version of NumPy older than 1.4 but I don't know where. How can I tell on which machine do I need to update my version of NumPy?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is a bug in Mllib init code

```
import numpy
if numpy.version.version < '1.4':
    raise Exception("MLlib requires NumPy 1.4+")
```

'1.10' is < from '1.4'
You can use NumPy 1.9.2 .

If you have to use NumPy 1.10 and don't want to upgrade to spark 1.5.1 .
Do a manual update to the code.
[https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/python/pyspark/mllib/**init**.py](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/python/pyspark/mllib/__init__.py)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have two versions of numpy installed and pyspark is importing the older one. To confirm this, you can do the following:

```
import numpy
print numpy.__version__
print numpy.__path__
```

This will probably give you 1.9.2 and it's path. Now do this:

```
import pyspark
print pyspark.numpy.__version__
print pyspark.numpy.__path__
```

Is it loading a different numpy from another path? If yes, removing it should most probably solve the issue.

Comment: I get the following error when I execute the second set of command 
`import pyspark'
'print pyspark.numpy.__version__'
'print pyspark.numpy.__path__`:
`---------------------------------------------------------------------------`
`AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)`
`<ipython-input-3-92586fa783d5> in <module>()`
`      1 import pyspark`
`----> 2 print pyspark.numpy.__version__`
`      3 print pyspark.numpy.__path__`
``
`AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'numpy'`
`